# How to use ContentChild annotation in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas

I try to make my own component that needs to have reference to a child element define by user.

In my html template i have this :

```
<fn-photo-editor fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="20px" class="coloredContainerX box">
    <div fxFlex.gt-sm="80" fxFlex="33" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
          <canvas fnPhotoEditorCanvas height="1080px" width="1920px" fxFlex dropzone="copy"></canvas>
    </div>
</fn-photo-editor>
```

In my Component.ts I have this :

```
@ContentChild(FnPhotoEditorCanvasDirective) canvas:HTMLCanvasElement;
```

and in my component template, just :

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

I use this directive on the canvas to get it's reference, since just using @ContentChild('canvas') seems to not work.

```
@Directive({
   selector: '[fnPhotoEditorCanvas]',
})
export class FnPhotoEditorCanvasDirective { }
```

So its this code, i get a reference to a FnPhotoEditorCanvasDirective object but it does not contains or represent a canvas object.

What i'm missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ContentChild('canvas')` works only if the element has a template variable `#canvas`

```
<canvas #canvas fnPhotoEditorCanvas height="1080px" width="1920px" fxFlex dropzone="copy"></canvas>
```

This query

```
@ContentChild(FnPhotoEditorCanvasDirective) canvas:HTMLCanvasElement;
```

will return the instance of the `FnPhotoEditorCanvasDirective`, not a `HTMLCanvasElement`.

Perhaps you want

```
@ContentChild(FnPhotoEditorCanvasDirective, {read: ElementRef}) canvas:HTMLCanvasElement;
```

then you can access the `HTMLCanvasElement` like

```
ngAfterContentInit() {
  this.canvas.nativeElement...
}
```

See also [angular 2 / typescript : get hold of an element in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681)